# Magento2 using graphql filter products that have special price in it

Tags: magento2, graphql

Magento2 How to filter products that have special price using GraphQL?

I want to get the collection of products in Response of product query in GraphQL that have special price.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For 'Special To' to 'Special From' filter:

Magento Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product:

Search these attributes and edit :

Attributes: special_to_date, special_from_date

Storefront Properties >

Use in Search : Yes

Visible in Advanced Search fields : Yes

Used in Sorting in Product Listing : Yes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use special_price in your products graphql query and apply filters

Comment: Hi can you provide graphql query